# How to parse JSON-C in .net

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I cannot use the Youtube APIs since they are not supported on WP so I opted to just use the JSON response. Seems like Youtube has changed there response type to JSON-C, how can I parse this?

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=relevance&q=lil+b&key=AIzaSyACjwJrIBICZxPb1x3JRq-FQ8iaei7LqXA&alt=json

I've tried Newtonsoft JSON but it does not support it either, any advice? Thanks!

Comment: JSON-C is just JSON.  Any JSON parser should work perfectly.

Comment: This is the error I get:
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Youtube_Metro.SearchResultsClass+RootObject[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below code. I have saved the json data as text file. Using jsonCsharp you can generate the model class. http://json2csharp.com/

```
var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\json.txt"); //get json data
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

public class PageInfo
{
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
    public int resultsPerPage { get; set; }
}

public class Id
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string channelId { get; set; }
    public string videoId { get; set; }
}

public class Default
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class High
{
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnails
{
    public Default @default { get; set; }
    public Medium medium { get; set; }
    public High high { get; set; }
}

public class Snippet
{
    public string publishedAt { get; set; }
    public string channelId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Thumbnails thumbnails { get; set; }
    public string channelTitle { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public Id id { get; set; }
    public Snippet snippet { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public PageInfo pageInfo { get; set; }
    public string nextPageToken { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```